# Is drywall compressible?

Tags: drywall

Suppose I have 1/2" drywall over the face of a joist, so there's lumber behind the entire run of drywall. Now, suppose I screw a 4"x4" piece of (approximately) 3/4" plywood to the face of the drywall, i.e. screws go through the plywood and the drywall into the joist. I need to tighten the screws as tightly as possible without risking damaging the plywood or stripping the hole. Will the drywall compress behind the plywood and create an indentation? In other words, will the face of the plywood be less than the thickness of the plywood in front of the drywall surrounding it?

(For my application it's important that the face of the plywood remains within 1/64" of its thickness in front of the drywall and doesn't sink into it more than that.)

Comment: In the real world nothing is exactly 3/4". What is your actual tolerance? Is a 32nd of an inch deviation too much, or 1/1000th?

Comment: How much surface area you are spreading the force over also matters a lot; obviously. A nail will go through supported wallboard, but the same force over a few square inches won't. Unsupported is of course a different question; the plaster will flex and may crack.

Comment: It will also depend on how tight you drive the screws in.  Just tight enough to hold the plywood or as tight as they will go.  Drywall does need some force to compress, less than plywood, more than foam.

Comment: We have done the reverse.  In Niches in the hall, where we knew my wife wanted to hang paintings, we installed the plywood first and the drywall on top.  This gave the identical texture/ finish down the hall, but allowed us to hang the paintings anywhere on the wall instead of being limited to studs and dwangs.  Incase, thats what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Good luck finding 3/4" plywood that's actually 3/4" thick in this decade and/or century. You'll probably need to buy 1" and shave it down to get that.

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: You could get some scrap material and try it out.

Comment: If you are working to 1/64 inch tolerances you should not be using plywood.  Or joists.    Or mounting anything to the walls of a house at all.   This question, I'm sorry, makes no sense as described.   Whether the drywall compresses or not is irrelevant, because no other part of the system is precise to that degree.  Can you explain more about what you're doing?

Comment: Why do you need to tighten the screws as tightly as possible?  Do you plan to drill holes in the plywood first?  What loads will be on this 4x4 piece of plywood?  It sure would help to know what your application is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.americangypsum.com/sites/default/files/2022-01/ga-235_gypsum_board_typical_mechanical_and_physical_properties.pdf

Gives 350 PSI for the compressive strength of 1/2" gypsum.

If you don't apply more than 16 X 350 = 5600 pounds force to your 4x4 (= 16 square inches) plywood it would be fine if the back is fully supported.

You are unlikely to get to even 1000 lbs force with typical screws before stripping out the threads in the wood.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-screws-allowable-withdrawal-load-d_1815.html

Gives 190 lbs "pullout" force per #10 (fairly large) screw 1.5" into spruce. 5 such screws would therefore be good to 950 lbs force if you managed to *fully* tighten them but not *overtighten* them to the point that they stripped the hole. 5 screws already seems like overkill for a mere 4x4 inch board, but would be manageable. 29 screws (to  approach 5600 lbs while ignoring the likley practical reduction in force from drilling so many holes so close to each other) seems rather impractical.